# Solving OR bounding sums of solutions to certain linear diophantine equations

Tags: elementary-number-theory, algebraic-geometry, diophantine-equations, upper-lower-bounds, linear-diophantine-equations

(This question arose during group work on classifying modular tensor categories.)

Let $p$ and $q$ be two distinct primes.  We seek integral solutions $\lbrace x_{i,j} \rbrace$ to the equation

\begin{align}
0 = \sum_{i=0}^{i=m} \sum_{j=m-i}^{j=m} p^i q^j x_{i,j}
\end{align}
subject to the requirements

\begin{align}
x_{m,m}=-1, \\ p \nmid x_{i,j}, \\ q \nmid x_{i,j}.
\end{align}

For example, when $p=5$, $q=7$, and $m=3$, we want to find integral solutions to the equation

\begin{align}
5^3 7^3 = 5^1 7^2 x_{1,2} + 5^2 7^1 x_{2,1} + 5^3 7^0 x_{3,0} + 5^0 7^3 x_{0,3} + 5^2 7^2 x_{2,2} + 5^3 7^1 x_{3,1} + 5^1 7^3 x_{1,3} + 5^3 7^2 x_{3,2} + 5^2 7^3 x_{2,3} 
\end{align}

such that none of the non-zero $x_{i,j}$ are divisible by 5 or 7. (We do allow $x_{i,j}$ to equal $0$.)

**Question 1.**  What algebraic geometry would be necessary to attack this problem?  It seems related to "finding integral points," so it could be much more difficult than I appreciate.

**Question 2.**  If determining integral solutions is too hard:  Is there a way we could at least give a bound for the sum of all the $x_{i,j}$ in terms of $m$?  That is, can we say

\begin{align}
\sum_{i=0}^{i=m} \sum_{j=m-i}^{j=m} x_{i,j} \, < \, f(m)
\end{align}

for some function $f(m)$ that doesn't grow too fast?